# Chrome extension- JavaScript to retrieve data from MySQL database and display in extention

Tags: javascript, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

we are creating a chrome extension that can able to retrieve a data from MYSQL database and display in extension.is it possible? second question is it possible to authenticate localhost .aspx website from java script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a native database connection I think it would be possible with npapi, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi. However it sounds to make like a big security risk due to the fact the username and password will be stored in the extension code that can be early access, a better solution would be to develop some http service/api that will connect to the database and return some information, then you can just make an ajax request to your service and display any information you want.
About the second question, you can make any http request just like the browser using chrome extensions.